# Woocommerce change products and quantity by url

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, e-commerce

I'm having some issues trying to change the number of products inside my cart.
I would like to control that using a URL, like this:

https://www.superpetcooler.com/?product_id=271&quantity=3

I'm able to retrieve product_id, but quantity wont work unless I set it maually. 
It's pretty weird, but if I add a dynamic value to $quantity, it doesn't work, but if I set as 3 inside add to cart function than it works just fine.

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'add_entries_to_cart' );

function add_entries_to_cart() {

    if ( strlen($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) ==  1  || $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/carrito' ){ 

        global $woocommerce;

        //$woocommerce->cart->empty_cart(); 

        //if I say $quantity = $..... wont work ???

        $quantity = '1';
        $product_id = 271;
        $woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id, $quantity );
    }   
}
```

How do I retrieve url parameters and atribute to add_to_cart inside functions.php ???

Here's my function.php
http://oneclickpaste.com/116110/

Thanks for anyhelp,

Comment: Your code is too long, and it is hosted in a third-party site. It is better if you include everything needed to understand your question in the question itself and provide a small piece of code that shows your difficulties. Read more here on how to create a [mcve].

Comment: just need to recieve get parameters from url INSIDE functions.php, anyone that did this in the past is able to help me without having to read my entire wordpress code. tks anyway

Answer (score 0):

> How do I retrieve url parameters and atribute to add_to_cart inside
>   functions.php ???

Use:

```
$_GET['product_id']
$_GET['quantity']
```

To grab the values in the URL.

```
$quantity = $_GET['quantity'];
$product_id = $_GET['product_id'];
```